# Spurious transmission when reading from serial port under linux (ttyUSB..)

Tags: linux, serial-port

I have a USB to RS485 converter connected to my linux box:

```
ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port
```

and it is currently st up using

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 raw 57600
```

So when I write some characters to the device (using `echo` or the similar on the console) I can monitor the *TX* LED flash and I can clearly identify the characters on an oscilloscope.

However, when I try to read characters from it something weird happens:

- I connected a simple teletyper to the RS485 output.
- When I type a couple of characters on it I can watch the oscilloscope and I notice the flashing of the *RX* LED in the converter.
- Then I start reading from the device, e.g. using `cat /dev/ttyUSB0`.
- Now whenever I type a character on the teletyper *both the RX and TX* LEDs flash, and as expected, I can see garbled signals on the oscilloscope as RS485 is only half-duplex. So basically the teletyper is using the lines at the same time as the linux box seems to send something, causing a clash.
- When I kill the `cat` process this stops and everything is fine again.

I have never witnessed this before. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

As you were.

It's the line discipline: The linux box has had its echo enabled, so it actually echoed back every incoming character.

The solution is to disable this:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 -echo
```